# Differential equation with pumps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A rectangular tank measures 2 meters by 3 meters and contains water of depth x(t) meters where t is measured on seconds. One pump pours in water at a rate of .05 cubic meters a second. A second pump pumps out water at a rate of .07+.02cos(wt). The period of the second pump is 1 hour. How would you go about setting up a differential equation for x(t)

So far I have 
x(t)=.05t -(.07+.02cos(wt))

Idk if I'm on the right track or not

Comment: any insight on this would be helpful :)

Comment: Note: $x(t)$ is the height whereas .05t is volume. And what value does $w$ need to be for the period to be 1 hour?

Comment: 3600 seconds. So I'd have to convert the volumes to a height in someway wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes to your question. But 3600 seconds is not the answer for $w$... After one period, $wt$ will equal $2\pi$, right?

Comment: Yes it would be 2pi wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, and $t=3600$ after one period, so what must $w$ be?

Comment: (2pi)/3600=w then right?

Comment: Yes. By the way, .07+.02cos(wt) is the *rate* (volume per unit time), not the *height* which is what your equation x(t)=.05t -(.07+.02cos(wt)) suggests (and is therefore incorrect).

Comment: I would have to divide by the cross sectional area wouldn't I? That would give me an output of meters

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Alright awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify: "That would give me an output of metres" ... per unit time! So $x(t)$ should be the derivative $dx/dt$.